# Warning message: NAs introduzidos por coerção

Tags: r

Estou com problema na formatação de “chr” para “num”.

Quando carrego a tabela a coluna `VA.VG` vem como `“chr”`, quando executo a alteração aparece o erro:

```
#carregar:
> t2019_12  = read.csv ("C:/Users/joao.moura/Desktop/Unificador/Apogi/12_2019 APOGI.csv", fill =F, dec=",", header = T, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F)

##Convertendo em "num":
> t2019_12$VA.VG <- as.numeric(t2019_12$VA.VG, rm.na = T)

Warning message:
NAs introduzidos por coerção
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(t2019_12$VA.VG)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(t2019_12$VA.VG, 20))`? E ainda, `rm.na` nunca é de certeza, poderá ser `na.rm` mas no caso da função `as.numeric` esse argumento não existe.

Comment: Nota: `read.csv2("C:/Users/joao.moura/Desktop/Unificador/Apogi/12_2019 APOGI.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` é mais simples e **é exatamente a mesma instrução**. `read.table` com certos valores dos argumentos dá `read.csv`, `read.csv2`, etc. Veja `help("read.table")` para detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

**Nota:** Isto não é uma resposta, é um comentário alargado, tentando explicar um possível caminho para resolver o problema.

Primeiro um conjunto de dados com uma coluna de classe `"character"` a transformar em `"numeric"`.

```
t2019_12 <- data.frame(VA.VG = c(1, pi, "NA", "12.345.6"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Agora, quando dá o erro da pergunta, o melhor é utilizar um vetor temporário onde ter valores `NA`, para depois determinar o que há de errado com esses elementos do vetor.

```
tmp <- as.numeric(t2019_12$VA.VG)
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

Se foram introduzidos `NA`'s, onde é que estão?

```
na <- which(is.na(tmp))
na
#[1] 3 4
```

E quais os valores que estavam no vetor original? Este é o passo fundamental, só se soubermos exatamente qual é o problema é que podemos resolvê-lo.

```
t2019_12$VA.VG[na]
#[1] "NA"        "12.345.6"
```

Bom, no primeiro caso parece que é mesmo um valor em falta, no segundo caso parece ser de se ter lido com `dec=","` um valor que tinha pontos a separar os milhares. O primeiro deve ser deixado como está mas o segundo vem de um erro que pode ser *corrigido*.

```
t2019_12$VA.VG[4] <- sub("\\.", "", t2019_12$VA.VG[4])
t2019_12$VA.VG <- as.numeric(t2019_12$VA.VG)
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

E a base é agora

```
t2019_12
#         VA.VG
#1     1.000000
#2     3.141593
#3           NA
#4 12345.600000
```

Limpeza final, já não precisamos de `tmp`.

```
rm(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que os seus números têm vírgulas neles (por exemplo, 1,234). Sugestão: primeiro faça seus fatores "limpos" com:

```
t2019_12$VA.VG <- gsub (",",t2019_12$VA.VG)
```

depois execute o comando:

```
t2019_12$VA.VG <- as.numeric(t2019_12$VA.VG)
```

Fonte: [How to convert factor to numeric in R without NAs introduced by coercion warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116442/how-to-convert-factor-to-numeric-in-r-without-nas-introduced-by-coercion-warning)